# What does "@+layout/" in android mean?

Tags: android, android-layout

In the layout resource file you can use `<include>` tag.
For example `<include layout="@layout/titlebar">`.
But what does "@+layout/" mean?
For example `<include layout="@+layout/titlebar">`.

I found this use in a layout file decoded by apktool from com.microsoft.office.word.apk.
Here is the whole xml file where "@+layout" appears.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.microsoft.office.ui.controls.widgets.Callout android:id="@id/moreOptionsCallout" app:dismissOnDeactivation="true" app:dismissOnEscape="true" app:dismissOnTapOutside="true" app:hideBorder="false" app:manualDismiss="false" app:moveFocusIntoCalloutAutomatically="true" app:palette="callout" app:respectBoundaryMargin="false" app:suppressDefaultAnimation="false" app:surfaceType="defaultChild" app:restrictFocusToLayout="true" style="@style/CalloutStyle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <com.microsoft.office.ui.controls.widgets.OfficeScrollView android:id="@id/optionsControlsViewCallout" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <include layout="@+layout/word_find_bar_control_options" />
    </com.microsoft.office.ui.controls.widgets.OfficeScrollView>
</com.microsoft.office.ui.controls.widgets.Callout>
```

Comment: I suggest to read documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource#idvalue

Comment: @uata: Neither of those pages show `@+layout` syntax.

Comment: I have not seen `@+layout` syntax used anywhere. Do you have some examples where you are seeing this?

Comment: You don't need a + before layout